# Why XYFocusKeyboardNavigation not working?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to prevent handling of onKeyDown events for keyboard arrows in CommandBar control.

I disabled XYFocusKeyboardNavigation, but it doesn't work - I am still able to navigate between buttons using "Left"/"Right" arrows. Why is it ?

```
<CommandBar XYFocusKeyboardNavigation="Disabled">
        <AppBarButton Label="menu">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <BitmapIcon UriSource="/Help/home.png"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="hideLeavesButton" Label="hide leaves" Click="HideLeavesButton_Click">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <BitmapIcon UriSource="/Help/hideLeaves.png"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
</CommandBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why XYFocusKeyboardNavigation not working?

It looks a bug, and I will report it, currently we have a workaround that prevent handling of onKeyDown events for  keyboard arrows. For the detail please refer the following.

```
Window.Current.Content.PreviewKeyDown += Content_PreviewKeyDown;
private void Content_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Left | e.Key == VirtualKey.Right | e.Key == VirtualKey.Up | e.Key == VirtualKey.Down)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it prevents handling of the event by parent controls

Answer (score 2):

It does look like a bug, I just got the same issue. Another simple way is to just set `IsTabStop="false"` to each button. Unfortunately, for complex UI this ends up being way more complicated than it should

Comment: Thanks. I think it should be: IsTabStop="false"